# Trying to download Java 8 update 121

Tags: java

I'm trying to download the java 8 version 121 update but I can not seem to find it on the java website any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

For older version of Java you can explore the Java archive: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html